# Dynamically generating a required module with Browserify and Gulp

Tags: javascript, dynamic, gulp, require, browserify

Is there a way to invoke Browserify (via Gulp) so that it includes a different file when `require`ing a module with a given name?

Briefly, the end result I would like is for my Browserify entry point, `main.js`:

```
var myPlatformSpecificImplmentation = require('./platform');
// go to town
```

to use the contents of `./path/to/platform-a.js` when I run `gulp js:platform-a` and `./path/to/platform-b.js` when I run `gulp js:platform-b`.

If I were using RequireJS, this would be as simple as modifying the `paths` option accordingly:

```
paths: {
  platform: './path/to/platform-a'
}
```

It would be great if I could somehow generate these modules dynamically via gulp's built-in streaming mechanism. In that case, I could, say, pipe a file into `gulp-template` and on into Browserify.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to use my [pathmodify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pathmodify) plugin like so:

`gulpfile.js`

```
var
  pathmod = require('pathmodify'),
  paths = {a: '/path/to/platform-a.js', b: '/path/to/platform-b.js'};

function platform (version) {
  return function () {
    return browserify('./main')
      .plugin(pathmod(), {mods: [
        pathmod.mod.id('app/platform', paths[version])
      ]})
      .bundle()
      .pipe(...);
  };
}

gulp.task('js:platform-a', platform('a'));
gulp.task('js:platform-b', platform('b'));
```

`main.js`

```
var myPlatformSpecificImplmentation = require('app/platform');
```

I've illustrated this with your `require()` string changed to `app/platform` because that allows the simplest implementation of pathmodify without collisions with other `./platform` relative paths in other files. But this *can* be implemented with pathmodify without risking collision (by testing the parent module [`main.js` in this case] pathname). If it's important to you to keep the `./platform` string I'll illustrate that.

Or you could use a transform. Take a look at `makeRequireTransform()` in  [benbria/browserify-transform-tools](https://github.com/benbria/browserify-transform-tools) if you don't want to roll your own.

> It would be great if I could somehow generate these modules dynamically via gulp's built-in streaming mechanism. In that case, I could, say, pipe a file into gulp-template and on into Browserify.

That's not out of the question, but it's not really easy to do. To do it without touching disk, you'd need to do something like create / `gulp.src()` a vinyl file and run it through whatever gulp plugins, then convert it to a stream to feed to browserify.